# Why do C macros act as pointers even though I am not passing variables by pointer

Tags: c, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a series of C macros to provide some generic data type capability for a struct, or grouping of structs that manages a dynamically allocated array.  At this point I have written several structs for each data type and am just starting to write a Macro function that can initialize the struct variables and allocated a user defined amount of memory.  The idea is to create one init function that can initialize any type of struct, so as long as it has the write form.  For this implementation I first have to instantiate a copy of the struct, which is then passed to the macro.  The macro ensures that the variables `allocated_length` and `active_length` is of type `size_t`.  Then it  determines the type of `array` by de-referencing it and using the`typeof` operator.  Finally it allocates memory to `ptr` and then checks to ensure the allocation was not returned as `NULL`.  However, in this example, I do not pass anything back to the main program, and I am not passing variables as a pointer.  Yet, somehow, the struct in the structs in the main program are able to see the modifications I made in the Macro.  How is this?

```
#define init_vector(vec_struct, aloc_length) ({size_t _a = (aloc_length);                   \
                                  size_t _b = 0;                    \
                                  typeof(vec_struct.array) ptr = malloc(aloc_length * sizeof(&vec_struct.array));   \
                                  if (ptr == NULL) {                        \
                                    perror("WARNING: ");                        \
                                    exit(0);                                    \
                                  }                                             \
                                  vec_struct.allocated_length = _a;             \
                                  vec_struct.active_length = _b;                    \
                                  vec_struct.array = ptr;       \
                                  })
typedef struct
{
    int *array;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
} IntVector;

typedef struct
{
    float *array;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
} FltVector;


int main() {
    IntVector int_vec;
    init_vector(int_vec, 30);
    printf("%ld\n", int_vec.allocated_length);

    FltVector float_vec;
    init_vector(float_vec, 20);
    printf("%ld\n", float_vec.allocated_length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C macros are not functions.  They operate purely by substituting text.  So if I write `#define ASSIGN(a, b) a = b`, and then later write `ASSIGN(x, y);`, it's just as if I'd written `x = y;`.  So `x` can get modified even though I didn't take its address.

Comment: Macros aren't passed values, they manipulate the text in your source file.

Comment: These days, you're usually much better off using an `inline` function, or perhaps a real function.  Function-like macros are pretty much obsolete these days.  They had their place back in the day, but there are extra things you have to keep track of when using them, so they can be badly confusing if you're not aware of those "extra things".  Why were you trying to make `init_vector` a macro?

Comment: @SteveSummit your comments is very pertinent to my approach and it is something that seems to carry varying opinions.  I come more from an object oriented background where generics are strongly built into the language.  In addition, I try hard, even in C to conform to the general coding practices you might get from Code Complete, which seems impossible to achieve in C.  The most important tenet of code practice being, never repeat code.

Comment: @SteveSummit Unfortunately, in C, between the signed and unsigned integers and real types as well as char's, there are 13 data types, which requires you to write the same function 13 times, if you want to write a robust library.  Inline functions, do not help with generics, leaving a Macro as the only viable alternative I can think of.  You can use ``void`` data types to help, but in my opinion it complicates the user interface too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand that macros are not functions. They simply replace text (or more precise tokens) before the actual C compilation starts.

The compiler will compile this code:

```
int main() {
    IntVector int_vec;
    ({size_t _a = (30); size_t _b = 0; typeof(int_vec.array) ptr = malloc(30 * sizeof(&int_vec.array)); if (ptr == 
# 32 "/app/example.c" 3 4
   ((void *)0)
# 32 "/app/example.c"
   ) { perror("WARNING: "); exit(0); } int_vec.allocated_length = _a; int_vec.active_length = _b; int_vec.array = ptr; });
    printf("%ld\n", int_vec.allocated_length);

    FltVector float_vec;
    ({size_t _a = (20); size_t _b = 0; typeof(float_vec.array) ptr = malloc(20 * sizeof(&float_vec.array)); if (ptr == 
# 36 "/app/example.c" 3 4
   ((void *)0)
# 36 "/app/example.c"
   ) { perror("WARNING: "); exit(0); } float_vec.allocated_length = _a; float_vec.active_length = _b; float_vec.array = ptr; });
    printf("%ld\n", float_vec.allocated_length);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ezvKfdn33

Is it something you have expected?

Macros have to be used with great caution and as little as possible.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer.  However, I am trying to dig deeper into the comment that macros should be used as little as possible.  I understand that they increase memory usage, which could be bad in certain applications.  However, without macro's I don't see any good way to build in generics so that you do not need to write the same function 13 times for each major data type.  You can use ``void`` data types in some cases, but that can lead to a messier than necessary interface. What are your thoughts?

Comment: If you are looking for more "generic" programming you should really think about C++. C i not a good "generic language"

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace:

> **Function-like macros**
>
> `#define identifier( parameters ) replacement-list`
>
> Function-like macros replace each occurrence of a defined identifier with replacement-list, additionally taking a number of arguments, which then replace corresponding occurrences of any of the parameters in the replacement-list.
>
> The syntax of a function-like macro invocation is similar to the syntax of a function call: each instance of the macro name followed by a ( as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of tokens that is replaced by the replacement-list. The sequence is terminated by the matching ) token, skipping intervening matched pairs of left and right parentheses.
>
> ...

That means (based on your example) that every occurrence of the identifier `init_vector` is replaced with the code after the last parentheses of the parameter list.

And each occurrence of the parameters `vec_struct`, `aloc_length` will also replaced accordingly.

At the end, it is not about functions and function calls, but replacement.

*"The preprocessor supports text macro replacement and function-like text macro replacement."*